# NPM package is causing error Error: Cannot find module '/home/user/project/package.json' in webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, bundle

I am trying to build a nodejs project into single file using webpack.js, following is my webpack.config.js

```html
const path = require('path');


module.exports = env => ({
  entry: ['./app.js'],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/'),
    filename: 'app.js',
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: ['babel-loader'],
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
    }],
  },
  node: {
    __dirname: false,
  },
  externals: ['tedious', 'pg-hstore'],
  target: 'node',
  plugins: [],
});
```

it builds and the distribution runs with node js v12, but then I import a package called @rodrigogs/mysql-events somewhere in the project, and then the error in the title started appearing. Do you have any idea what can be wrong with this package?

Comment: Hi there! Can you show us the file structure of your repository? I think webpack configuration needs to be in the same directory as the root directory of package.json

Comment: @destroyer22719, thanks for the reply!, I created a minimal test case with only one line  app.js importing @rodrigogs/mysql-events, webpack config and package.json are correct, and they build correctly when this library is not included. I will try to create the test case tomorrow and link it here.